# Can't print sql queries to stdout

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

I am trying to fetch sql queries after they are executed so that I can check what data are fed into the query that got framed and use it for my analysis. But I am not able to do so.
I am trying to see the query that got framed after ? values are substitutes for example as seen in bracket. (select * from dish where DishId = 2 and ItemNumber = 23)

```
var xyz = getDishByDishId: (id, item, callback) => {
  pool.query(
    `select * from dish where DishId = ? and ItemNumber = ?`, [id, item],
    (error, results, fields) => {
      if (error) {
        callback(error);
      }
      return callback(null, results[0]);
    }
  );
  console.log(xyz.sql); //this just print the query with ? in it
}
```

Comment: That looks like a syntax error. What is `getDishByDishId:` supposed to mean?

Comment: I don't think the SQL with the placeholders replaced is saved anywhere. In many cases the substitution isn't done by node.js, it's done by MySQL itself.